# Create HTML table from numbers elements of array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the variable `$count` that contains the total elements of my array.
I want to insert the html code to another variable that contains a table of as many lines as the lines of variable $count.
how can I do ?

```
<?php 
$count=5;
$html="<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>"
?>
```

Comment: Lines? Do you mean rows? Where does the content for the table come from?

Comment: Possibly [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-repeat.php) is what you need.

Comment: why was this tagged as javascript? I guess you're open to both methods?

Comment: @Joshua Dannemann why did you remove the OP's javascript tag? Maybe he's looking to get a JS equivalent?

Comment: no idea why everyone's answers are getting downvoted here. Whoever's doing it, at least leave a comment somewhere.

Comment: @TinyGiant yeah, seems like there were 2 different editors here, one reverting back to the other words and then removing the js tag. The question should probably be rolled back to its original or the 1st revision. Edit: You removed your comment.

Comment: @TinyGiant No worries. I'm trying to decide which one it should be rolled back to. Edit: I chose the 1st revision.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I removed the JavaScript tag because it is not clear that the question has anything whatsoever to do with JavaScript. This is PHP and HTML right?

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann I can understand that the OP's question is unclear. We don't know what's going in the guy's head lol!. Maybe he was looking for a js solution or is already using js. All of this being "unclear" which is why the question has been closed accordingly. Nobody's giving you heck here; least I wasn't ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities to do this.

Use a loop:

```
$table = '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $table .= '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

or you could use str_repeat

```
$table = '<table>';
$table .= str_repeat('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>', $count);
$table .= '</table>';
```

or many others - depends on your needs

Comment: But who would want to create empty tables without any ids? =)

Comment: I have no idea.. maybe he will tell us

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<?php 
$count = 5; 
?>

<table>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you explain the downvote please? So i will be able to correct myself by my mistakes and to improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure on the question (it's incredibly vague), but I'll try to help.

```
<?php
$count = 5;
$html = "<table>";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $html .= "<tr><td>New Row!</td></tr>";
}

$html .= "</table>";
```

Use this for rows.

```
<?php
$count = 5;
$html = "<table><tr>";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $html .= "<td>New column!</td>";
}

$html .= "</tr></table>";
```

Use this for columns.

Combine the two examples for a 100% dynamic table with dynamic rows and columns. If you've got an array, you'd be better off just using a `foreach`:

```
<?php
$array = array( array('Col1'=>'Val1', 'Col2'=>'Val2', 'Col3'=>'Val3'), array('Col1'=>'Test', 'Col2'=>'Test', 'Col3'=>'Test') );
$html = "<table>\n\t<tr>";

//Columns
foreach(array_key($array[0]) as $col){
    $html .= "\n\t\t<td>{$col}</td>";
}

$html .= "\n\t</tr>";

//Rows
foreach($array as $row){
    $html .= "\n\t<tr>";

    foreach($row as $rowcol){
        $html .= "\n\t\t<td>{$rowcol}</td>";
    }

    $html .= "\n</tr>";
}

$html .= "</table>";
```

Yes I'm a little OCD about the newlines and tabs.

If you can update your question with a use-case I can probably provide a better, more accurate example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways. By using a foreach or a for/while cycle.

In my opinion you can go ahead and use the foreach to iterate your array().

```
<?php $array= array('blue', 1, 3, 'red', 'monkey'); ?>
<table>
<?php foreach($array as $value): ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $value ?></td>
   </tr>';
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
?>
```

For me it's the cleaner way to iterate an array. If you just want to make multiple columns/rows on a table than use a `for($i=0; $i<$count; i++)` instead.